# System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

При нажатии на кнопку не вызывается ICommand SelectImage и собственно в консоли сыпятся ошибки: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectImage' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1721744223)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectImage; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1721744223); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

MainViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand SelectImage { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
      SelectImage = new RelayCommand(imageObject =>
      {
           _logger.LogError("Clicked");
      });

      Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel ItemHeight="200" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button 
                        Command="{Binding SelectImage}",
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Name="imageContainer"
                        >
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Проблема точно не в том, что ILogger не выводит сообщение в консоль, пробовал bind'ить к другой кнопки, которая не находилась в ItemsControl

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом, а так - классика `Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`

Comment: @aepot Хорошо. Ошибка пропала, но срабатывание  обработчика по прежнему не происходит.

Comment: Вы можете код нормально вставить? Где у вас присваивается значение `SelectImage`? В конструкторе вьюмодели? Если нет, перенесите в конструктор.

Comment: @aepot выложил код

Comment: Не `DataContext.Find`, а `DataContext.SelectImage`. По имени команды.

Comment: @aepot Да это я понял, просто тестил другую команду и забыл вернуть SelectImage, поэтому внёс еще исправления. Так что проблема осталась

Comment: Код не меняйте! У вас на картинке не было привязки с `RelativeSource`. Вы дали код и спрашиваете: почему выскакивает ошибка? Вам дали решение, оно вам помогло, вопрос, который был изначально, закрыт. Сейчас ваш код, данную ошибку (что в заголовке и в тексте вопроса) не выдает и как прикажете будущим читателям понимать это? То, что у вас не работает обработчик - это совершенно уже другая проблема и другой вопрос, который не связан с данной ошибкой.

Comment: @aepot Да, я понял, прошу прощения, щас вставлю старый код. Я понял в чем была проблема, нужно было указать за место AncestorType=Window - AncestorType=Page. Так что огромное спасибо

Comment: Ну я же не знал, что у вас там `Page`. Не за что.